Show that $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\tilde{\mu}$ and that the circle action on $\tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free
Assume we have a Hamiltonian action of $S^1$ on $(M, ω)$ with moment map $\mu_M : M → \Bbb R $and consider
the action of $S^1$ on $(\Bbb R^2, ω_0)$ by rotation which has moment map
$\mu_{\Bbb R_2} : \Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R, \mu_{\Bbb R_2}(x) = −1/2 (∥x∥^2)$
Form the diagonal action of $S^1$ on $M × \Bbb R^2$. Show that if $\epsilon > 0$ is a regular value for $\mu_M$ and the
circle action on $\mu_M^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free, then $\epsilon$ is also a regular value for
$\tilde \mu = \mu_M + \mu_{\Bbb R_2} : M × \Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R$
and the circle acts freely on $\tilde \mu^{−1}(\epsilon)$ and hence we can perform symplectic reduction to obtain a symplectic structure on
$M_{[>\epsilon]} =\tilde \mu^{−1}(\epsilon)/S^1$,
My try:
To show that $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\tilde{\mu}$ and that the circle action on $\tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free, we need to demonstrate two things that $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\tilde{\mu}$ and that the circle action on $\tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free.
Let's do that: Since $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\mu_M$, every point $p \in \mu_M^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is a regular point for $\mu_M$. Similarly, $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ since it is a constant function. Now, if $\epsilon$ is a regular value for both $\mu_M$ and $\mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}$, then it is also a regular value for $\tilde{\mu} = \mu_M + \mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}$, as the sum of regular functions is regular.
To prove the freeness of the circle action on $\tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)$: Suppose $(p, q) \in \tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)$, where $p \in M$ and $q \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, we have $\mu_M(p) + \mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}(q) = \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\mu_M$, the preimage $\mu_M^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$. Additionally, the circle action on $\mu_M^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free by assumption. Therefore, for any nontrivial element $g \in S^1$, $g \cdot p \neq p$ unless $p$ is on the fixed point set of the circle action. Similarly, since $\mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is constant along the orbits of the circle action on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is also free. Thus, the circle action on $\tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free.
Since $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\tilde{\mu}$ and the circle action on $\tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free, we can perform symplectic reduction to obtain a symplectic structure on the quotient space $M_{[>\epsilon]} = \tilde{\mu}^{-1}(\epsilon)/S^1$.
Could you give me feedback on this proof? Is it correct? If not, how do I fix it?

Your proof that $\epsilon$ is a regular value for $\tilde\mu$ doesn't really make sense. $\mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is not a constant function! Recall what the definition of regular value is. It is certainly not true that a regular value for two functions is a regular value of the sum.

Also, you have not made clear the relationship between $\mu_M^{-1}(\epsilon)$ and $\tilde\mu^{-1}(\epsilon)$ in a way which would allow you to conclude that the action of $S^1$ on $\mu^{-1}(\epsilon)$ is free. In fact, the action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not free, $0$ is a fixed point.

To phrase J.V.Gaiter's points slightly differently: you noticed for yourself that we need to consider all $(p,q)\in M\times \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mu_M(p)+\mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}(q)=\epsilon$, which does not force any of the two summands to equal $\epsilon$, but rather $\mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}(q)=\lambda$ and $\mu_M(p)=\epsilon -\lambda$ for $\lambda \le 0$. The fact that you only need to assume regularity of $[\mu_M = \epsilon]$ and freeness on this set to reach the conclusion hints at a difference of behavior of $[\mu_{\mathbb{R}^2}= \lambda]$ depending on whether $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda < 0$.
